# selected row color for striped table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, model-view-controller, datatable

I want the selected row of my table to have a certain background color. 
My table is striped and it only works for the white rows. I am working with datatables.net.

I expect the grey rows to be the same color if selected then the white rows. But with this code it turns the white rows grey with a click. However if i only use the first if else block it works for the white rows. What am I doing wrong?

```js
if (this.style.background == 'white') {
  $(this).css('background', '#cce6ff');
} else {
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
}

if (this.style.background == 'lightgrey' && this.style.background != 'white') {
  $(this).css('background', '#cce6ff');
} else if (this.style.background != 'white') {
  $(this).css('background', 'lightgrey');
}
```

this also doesn't work:

```
  if (this.style.background == 'white'){
        $(this).css('background', '#b6c7db');
        break;
    }else{
        $(this).css('background', 'white');
        break;
    }
    if (this.style.background == 'lightgrey' && this.style.background != 'white'){
        $(this).css('background', '#cce6ff');

    }else if (this.style.background != 'white'){
        $(this).css('background', 'lightgrey');}
```

Comment: and if I use a # color like #7F7F7F it doesnt work at all...

Comment: Why not do this in CSS and save this headache

Comment: Hope the speliing is correct - lightgray instead of lightgrey

Comment: it doesn't work in css.. I tried: tr.selected { background: #cce6ff !important}

Comment: You ask first if it is white if so then you set it to the color #cce6ff. Then in the if else you ask is not white then set it to gray. That's why he set it to gray.

Comment: @Sonia there are both colors .. one is slightly lighter than the other

Comment: @sulox32 the white rows turn grey, and the grey rows just stay the way they are

Comment: Jes! You dou first `if (this.style.background == 'white') {
  $(this).css('background', '#cce6ff');` and then override it with  `else if (this.style.background != 'white') {
  $(this).css('background', 'lightgrey');` to grey.

Comment: so how can I get the row #cce6ff for the row, no matter what color the row in a striped table has..?

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? Maybe drop your work into JSFiddle @ZaraZahara

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `this` actually refers to the row. If not, you will need to adjust it to target the row.

That said, assuming that datatables is already adding the selected class to the row, you can use CSS to target it.

Then, if the above is still not working, it's highly likely you need to use `!important` to force the value, which is no doubt being overwritten somewhere else

**Method 2**: 
You should do this with the CSS rule you have and avoid checking the current color. On select, remove the `selected` class from all rows and toggle it on the row being selected.

Is your code inside a click handler? You have `break` statements in your second snippet, is this code inside a loop? I feel that you have some misconception about conditional statements, but I have trouble understanding what those code snippets are trying to achieve -- for example, `this.style.background == 'lightgrey' && this.style.background != 'white'` is unnecessarily verbose, if the background equals `lightgrey`, then it won't be equal to `white`, the second comparison can be removed.

Comment: table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
    background-color: pink !important;
} 
Things like this dont work...unfortunately

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? Maybe drop your work into JSFiddle @ZaraZahara

Comment: you need to apply it to the TD/TH i.e.  `table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td, table.dataTable tbody tr.selected th { background-color: white; }` @ZaraZahara

Comment: @ZaraZahara did it help?